# Podio is throwing PodioBadRequestError invalid_value int when trying to add an item that has multiple tags within its fields

Tags: php, json, api, podio

I am trying to add a customer(Podio item) to my Podio app. This customer is being added programmatically from within a php application. There are several fields present on the customer: Name, Address, Email, Title, Phone Number, and an array of Tags. When a tag is added the color changes to highlight it.
In previous iterations I have been successful adding a different tag(newsletter_subscribed) using the ID of the tag value that I want highlighted. Now when I try to add another tag(hospital, clinic, or urgent_care) it is throwing a PodioBadRequestError. The error cited is that the ID being used is and invalid type(integer).

I got the values of the tag ID's by looking at the JSON returned when an existing customer created manually within my Podio customer application. When I look at the ID fields in the JSON they are most definitely integers, I have tried strings as well. Everything I try throws the 400 Bad Request on the ID that I am trying to add.
I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is throwing the error when I add the tag ID's.

Below is the way that the application is put together:

This is the code that builds and sends the request:

```
public function addToPodio()
{
         $address = $this->Address . ", " .
                    $this->Address2 . ", " .
                    $this->City . ", " .
                    $this->State . " " .
                    $this->Zip;
         
         $item = [
            'fields' => [
                'name'          => $this->PrimaryContactFirstName,
                'last-name'     => $this->PrimaryContactLastName,
                'email-address' => ['type' => 'work', 'value' => $this->PrimaryContactEmail],
                'phone-number'  => ['type' => 'work', 'value' => $this->PrimaryContactPhone],
                'address'       => $address,
                'organization'  => [$this->CompanyName],
                'tags-2' => []
             ],
           ];

           if ($this->Newsletter && defined('PODIO_NEWSLETTER_TAG_ID')){
            $item['fields']['tags-2'][] = PODIO_NEWSLETTER_TAG_ID;
           }

           if($this->OrganizationType && defined('PODIO_ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID')){
        
            if($this->OrganizationType == "Clinic"){
                $item['fields']['tags-2'][] = PODIO_ORGANIZATION_TYPE_CLINIC_TAG_ID;
            }
            else if($this->OrganizationType == "Hospital"){
                $item['fields']['tags-2'][] = PODIO_ORGANIZATION_TYPE_HOSPITAL_TAG_ID;
            }
      
        try {
             //This is where the request is being made
            $customer = PodioItem::create(PODIO_CUSTOMER_APP_ID, $item);
            $this->PodioId = $customer->item_id;
            $this->write();

         } catch (Exception $e) {
           error_log('We encountered an error adding your item to Podio' . $e);
           return 'An error occurred while updating Podio. Please try again. If the error...';
         }
```

This is the PHP $item that is being passed to the request that gets sent to the Podio API:

```
    Array
    (
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [name] => Joe
                [last-name] => Test
                [phone-number] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => work
                        [value] => 8675309
                    )

                [address] => 123 Main Road, , East Test, NY 12345
                [organization] => Array
                    (
                       [0] => Another Test
                    )

                [tags-2] => Array
                    (
                       [0] => 16
                       [1] => 96
                    )

           )

    )
```

This is the config file with the all of the constants, secrets tokens and ID's needed to connect to the Podio API, authenticate and all of that stuff. Obfuscated Example below:

```
define('PODIO_CUSTOMER_APP_ID', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');
define('PODIO_CUSTOMER_APP_TOKEN', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');
define('PODIO_CLIENT_SECRET', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');
define('PODIO_CLIENT_ID', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');
define('PODIO_ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxx');
define('PODIO_NEWSLETTER_TAG_ID', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');
define('PODIO_ORGANIZATION_TYPE_CLINIC_TAG_ID', 'xxxxx-obfuscated-xxxxx');

Podio::setup(PODIO_CLIENT_ID, PODIO_CLIENT_SECRET, [
    'session_manager' => Injector::inst()->get(PodioSession::class),
    'curl_options' => array(),
 ]);
```

Below is the JSON that I used to get the values of the ID's. I got this from a postman request to the API. The basic form of the request without all of the authentication present looked like:

```
podio.com/MY_PODIO_ACCOUNT_NAME/app/APPLICATION_ID/item/ITEM_ID
```

- Please note: I removed many of the main fields like Address and Organization for brevity's sake, so it won't match completely the PHP request object above.

  ```
    {
      "id": 0000,
      "item_id": 00000,
      "revision": 0,
      "app": null,
      "app_item_id": 00000,
      "app_item_id_formatted": "PODIO_Field_ID:00000",
      "external_id": null,
      "title": "TEST ITEM",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": 0000,
          "field_id": 0000,
          "type": "text",
          "external_id": "name",
          "label": "First Name",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "Joe"
            }
          ],
          "config": {
            "settings": {
              "format": "plain",
              "size": "small"
            },
            "mapping": "contact_name",
            "label": "First Name"
          },
          "humanized_value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "id": 0000,
          "field_id": 0000,
          "type": "text",
          "external_id": "last-name",
          "label": "Last Name",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "<p>Test<br /></p>"
            }
          ],
          "config": {
            "settings": {
              "format": "html",
              "size": "large"
            },
            "mapping": null,
            "label": "Last Name"
          },
          "humanized_value": "Test"
        },
        {
          "id": 0000,
          "field_id": 0000,
          "type": "phone",
          "external_id": "phone-number",
          "label": "Phone Number",
          "values": [
            {
              "type": "work",
              "value": "867-5309"
            }
          ],
          "config": {
            "settings": {
              "call_link_scheme": "callto",
              "possible_types": [
                "mobile",
                "work",
                "home",
                "main",
                "work_fax",
                "private_fax",
                "other"
              ]
            },
            "mapping": "contact_phone",
            "label": "Phone Number"
          },
          "humanized_value": "8675309"
        },
        {
          "id": 11111,
          "field_id": 11111,
          "type": "category",
          "external_id": "tags-2",
          "label": "Tags",
          "values": [
            {
              "value": {
                "status": "active",
                "text": "Clinic",
                "id": 16,
                "color": "DCEBD8"
              }   
            },
            {
              "value": {
                "status": "active",
                "text": "Newlsetter_subscribed",
                "id": 96,
                "color": "DCEBD8"
              }
           }
          ],
          "config": {
            "settings": {
              "multiple": true,
              "options": [
                {
                  "status": "active",
                  "text": "Mktng:test1/2020",
                  "id": 150,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                },
                {
                  "status": "active",
                  "text": "Mktng:Test2/2020",
                  "id": 3,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                },
                {
                  "status": "active",
                  "text": "SampleTest",
                  "id": 48,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                },
                {
                  "status": "deleted",
                  "text": "Test Center",
                  "id": 139,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                },
                {
                  "status": "deleted",
                  "text": "Sample Center",
                  "id": 99,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                },
                {
                  "status": "deleted",
                  "text": "Testing Center",
                  "id": 140,
                  "color": "DCEBD8"
                }
              ],
              "display": "inline"
            },
            "mapping": null,
            "label": "Tags"
          },
          "humanized_value": "Clinic; Newsletter;"
        }
  ```

this JSON continues for pages and pages, I only included the relevant fields for my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is being thrown because of the organization value, not the tags value.

For a category field, an array of integer indices is correct.

```
[tags-2] => [ 16, 96 ]
```

For an app field, you need to provide an array of integer item ID's.

```
[organization] => [ 12345 ]
```

But your code above is sending an array of strings:

```
[organization] => [ "Another Test" ]
```

That won't work.